# parametrized build plugin jenkins is not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a problem with parametrized build plugin in jenkins.

I have configured 2 jobs.

job A and job B

Job A will send the parameters to Job B

But the problem is the values are never being sent from job A to job B

**Job A configuration**
[Job A config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3x5O.jpg)

**Job B configuration**
[Job B config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg4x1.jpg)

[ I am using jenkins version 2.7.2 ]

Please help me with the above problem

Comment: Try archive version (2.29) 
http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/parameterized-trigger/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to declare COPYJOB as a build parameter in Job B. Only then will it be picked up as an environment variable when passed from Job A, and you will then be able to reference it like $COPYJOB in your goals